# html5/JavaScript or WPF/C# for diagramming application

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, html

I'm going to develop diagramming app with support for designing SQL databases.

I have experience with WPF (about 2 years) and with html5/js (about a year)

This should be quick and easy-to-use app (working on linux and android is just a wish)

I'm looking for advice, should I use WPF or Html5 ?

Thanks :)

Comment: "Should I use this or that?" questions don't belong here. "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely **solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.**" There's no definite answer here.

Comment: You may consider using JQuerry which is the richest javascript library for easily developing countless fancy application like this.

Comment: I use jQuery all the time, but it can't help in this situation.................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with WPF.

I don't think WPF is so much easier than HTML (it feels a little overdesigned here and there), but prototyping in C# is easier as it is a much richer language than javascript. Not to mention the benefits of typesafety.